# Add row to a table with Jquery,but don't need its value

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I clone a row in a table without cloning the values of the input elements inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576565/how-can-i-clone-a-row-in-a-table-without-cloning-the-values-of-the-input-elements)

i am trying to add a row to a table.i found that we can use clone . my table has two text boxes in it in two different tr's .cloning the last row is also duplicating the values in my textbox's which i don't want ?Any ideas ???

my code

```
$("#table-1 tr:last").clone();
```

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question under a different account.  Voting to close, this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576565/how-can-i-clone-a-row-in-a-table-without-cloning-the-values-of-the-input-elements

Answer (score 1):

may be somthing like this

```
 $("#table-1 tr:last").clone().find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a row with the inputs, but not the values, you could do something like what you have, and just clear the values:

```
var row = $("#table-1 tr:last").clone();
row.find( 'input' ).each( function(){
    $( this ).val( '' )
});
row.appendTo( "#table-1" )
```

Comment: I'm assuming, with my answer, that your row has inputs.. If you could post the html of the row, we could help better.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the input fields after cloning :

```
var row = $("#table-1 tr:last").clone().find(':input').val('').end();

// then add the row at the end of the table
$("#table-1").append(row);
```