# JavaScript to jQuery (function to add row to table)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to convert JavaScript to jQuery? The JavaScript code is:

```
function addRow()
{       
     var table = document.getElementById("table2");     
     var numOfRows = table.rows.length;     
     var numOfCols = table.rows[numOfRows-1].cells.length;                    
     var newRow = table.insertRow(numOfRows);

     for (var j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++) {                    
          newCell = newRow.insertCell(j);                    
          newCell.innerHTML = "add";
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to jQuery?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: Because the javascript code should be done using jquery framework...

Comment: @apolo90 the reason you are getting downvotes is because when you ask your exact question it displays in the recommended answers.

Comment: Don't use jQuery for the sake of using jQuery. The library is significantly slower than native javascript, especially on small pieces of code like this.

Comment: I can kind of see why he would want to do it? jquery is much easier to maintain and is in my opinion worth the slower runtime :)

Comment: duplicate? [Using Append to Copy Table Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503279/using-append-to-copy-table-row-would-like-to-create-unique-ids)

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/hMJPH/)**

```
 $('#addRow').click(function(){
   var row = $('#table2 tr:eq(0)').clone();
   $(row).find('td').html('add');
   $('#table2').append(row);
});

<table id='table2'>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
​<input type='button' id='addRow' value='click' />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code that add a new row after the last, I don0t know shich parameters you need

```
function addRow()
{       
   $('#table2 tr:last').after('<tr><td>some </td></tr><tr><td>text</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: Is that pasta from chris' duplicate link?

Comment: Thank you very much but doesn't work :S

Comment: Return some error of javascript?

Comment: ok perfect! you are welcome